# How do I create a Makefile that will compile and run java code with command line arguments?

Tags: java, compilation, makefile, executable

I need to be able to compile my program, then execute it 3 different times with a different .txt file as the first command line argument each time, and this all needs to be done with a single "make" command.  The respective terminal commands for what I want my Makefile to do are as follows:

```
javac MainDriver.java FSA.java State.java Transition.java
java MainDriver test1.txt
java MainDriver test2.txt
java MainDriver test3.txt
```

Here's what I currently have:

```
JC = javac
JCR = java

.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
    $(JC) $*.java

CLASSES = \
    MainDriver.java \
    FSA.java \
    State.java \
    Transition.java 

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
    $(RM) *.class *~
```

Comment: Would you consider using Apache Ant instead of make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JC = javac
JCR = java

.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
    $(JC) $*.java

CLASSES = \
    MainDriver.java \
    FSA.java \
    State.java \
    Transition.java 

TXT_FILES = \
    test1.txt \
    test2.txt \
    test3.txt \

default: classes exec-tests

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
    $(RM) *.class *~

exec-tests: classes
    set -e; \
    for file in $(TXT_FILES); do $(JCR) MainDriver $$file; done;


.PHONY: default clean classes exec-tests
```

Comment: I tried using this and got the following error for each test:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test1/txt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test1.txt
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)`

Comment: Oops missed the actual binary. Have updated the answer. I also assume that you want to run all of the binaries with all the text files. Is that correct ?

Comment: Also added a set -e, so that it stops on the first error. Remove that line if you do not want that behavior.

Comment: Works great, thanks! Do you happen to know why it causes that exception at the end? Just curious.

Comment: You mean with the first version of the Makefile ? That was because it was missing the program name in the for loop.

Comment: No whenever I use the most recent version, it gives the following:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
make: *** [exec-tests] Error 1`

Comment: It looks like you do not have a **public static void main()** function wihtin all of your java files.

Comment: Okay reading your question again, it looks to me that you only have only program which is split across multiple files and there is only one main() function all together. Is that correct ? I've updated the Makefile to invoke only MainDriver with all 3 text files.

Comment: It would be appreciated if you accept the answer since the solution worked for you ;)

Comment: Haha my apologies, I'm new to stackoverflow--answer accepted!